# What is the substring equivalent in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting JSON files but each file has a code/ID with it, in the beginning
i am trying to make a standard way to crop the strings no matter how the code/ID changes.

so these are 2 JSON files:

```
a:12{/*JSON DATA HERE*/}
a:130 {/*JSON DATA HERE*/}
a:1 {/*JSON DATA HERE*/}
```

i did not find a way to locate the first occurrence of "{" and include it in the new string that will also include the rest of the JSON string.

in JAVA it would go something like that, but i need it in php:

```
String myjson = "a:130{/*JSON here*/}";
String newjson = myjson.substring(myjson.indexOf("{"), myjson.length());
```

how can i do that in php?

Comment: `substr` read the docs on how to use it : http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: already did that, but what i didnt find is indoxOf equivalent

Comment: @Hazo `strpos`.

Comment: Read the chapter on strings in any PHP textbook or tutorial, they should explain all the common functions like this.

Comment: @Hazo then change the title of your question, Barmar has just given you what you are looking for ;)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: This really seems to be a PHP serialized array (through `serialize` / `unserialize`) and not JSON. PHP uses `a:<count>{...}` to indicate a serialized array. If you can trust the data (i.e. not user submitted but generated by a trusted application), don't parse it yourself and use `unserialize` instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks this is what i needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really seems to be a PHP serialized array (through [serialize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) / [unserialize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)) and not JSON.

PHP uses `a:<count>{...}` to indicate a serialized array in its format.

If you can *trust the data* (i.e. not user submitted but generated by a *trusted application*), don't parse it yourself and use unserialize instead.

The reason why you never should use `unserialize` on user submitted data that you can't verify independently is that it is able to create objects of a user specific selection, and if the object defines `__wakeup`, it [might be able to coerce the object into performing any operation the attacker want](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection). This is also why there is a large warning on the unserialize manual page.